# REST API hot reload

Tags: restful-architecture

I need to develop a REST API backend.
I didn't choose yet any framework/language.
However one of my main requirements is that I should be able to achieve continuous integration by deploying frequent changes to the backend without loosing frontend availability .

I don't understand if I should take architectural/deployment decisions (swapping backend versions? hot reload?) Or should I rather  prefer a particular language/framework (eg. interpreted php vs a java framework?)

I'm not current in java anymore and I remember long application server reload time at any change. I'm aware of more modern frameworks which seems to include from the beginning the hot reload concept (play?spring?) But I've never tried any of them.

I'm looking for something "easy", stable, reliable and more or less "well known" as I don't have many resources.

Any suggestion or proposal welcome.

Answer (score 1):

REST implies HTTP. Put two or more backends behind a http load balancer (e.g. haproxy). As backends fail or are restarted, the API is available all the time.